# How to change "surname" to "lastname" field in signup form in moodle

Tags: moodle

I want to change "surname" to "lastname" field  in signup form in moodle. how to do it?

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

1:Login as admin to your mooodle site
2: go to Site administration -> Language -> Language customisation
3: Select English in the dropdown menu, then click on button "Open language              pack for editing" and wait for loading, then click on "Continue"
4:Select all files in the box "Show strings of these components" (unless you know the exact component where your string lives) and type "Surname" in box "Only strings containing"
5:You'll get 4 strings where you can change what you want in "Local customisation"
Click on "Save changes to the language pack".
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the surname from the registration form by editing
User/editlib.php
//$necessarynames = array('firstname', 'lastname');
Change to
$necessarynames = array('firstname'